# ADFDI performance issue while uploading more than 1000 records

Tags: integration, oracle12c, desktop, oracle-adf

I have developed ADF DI excelsheet to upload bulk data through it. But while I keep it to upload 1000 data it takes much amount of time nearly 35 minutes.

I have tried to reduced batch size from 500 to 50 and then 10.

But there is no improvement in upload part.
I have tried to generate the log file from excel sheet to monitor the process. In that, there is log pause after batch 71 commit.

Here Batch 71 - 10 * 71 = 710 data processed. It can be error nous and successful both.

Any suggestions for improvement will be appreciated and much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally leave the commit batch size at 100.
The basic log files (Doc ID 2094378.1) will provide some upload stats.
Make sure you are using the latest version of the add-in (Doc ID 2244542.1)

The main determinant of upload throughput is backend business logic, particularly expensive validations in the model layer (e.g. ViewObject) and/or costly SQL queries.

You can use JDeveloper to do an elapsed time profile of the server to look for bottlenecks there.